# Magento extension install ok but not show on the admin setting part

Tags: magento

I installed the extention `Advanced Smtp - ArtsOn.IT` by `Magento Connect manager`.
in the **Channel: connect.magentocommerce.com/community** part: is shows:

```
Package Name    Installed   Actions     
ArtsOnIT_AdvancedSmtp   0.1.7 (stable)          Provide the support for all the smtp server (Autentication, SSL)
```

but at the system---> configration-->Advanced part,there is no `Advanced Smtp - ArtsOn.IT` setting. why?how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the Magento cache and log out, and then log back in.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file and folder permissions. They're probably limited, change to read&write for both files and directories of your new extension, and it should work immediately. It does not have anything to do with the cache after all.